# Latin to English alphabet hashing

Tags: python, nlp

I have to convert all the latin characters to their corresponding English alphabets. Can I use Python to do it? Or is there a mapping available?

Unicode values to non-unicode characters

`Ramírez Sánchez` should be converted to `Ramirez Sanchez`.

Comment: English alphabet *is* the latin alphabet.  Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like what you want is accent removal.  You can do this with:

```
def strip_accents(text):
    return ''.join(char for char in
                   unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', text)
                   if unicodedata.category(char) != 'Mn')

>>> strip_accents('áéíñóúü')
'aeinouu'
>>> strip_accents('Ramírez Sánchez')
'Ramirez Sanchez'
```

This works fine for Spanish, but note that it doesn't always work for other languages.

```
>>> strip_accents('ø')
'ø'
```