# Sorting Non-English Characters Alphabetically(ç, ş, ö) (Python-3x)

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sorting, arraylist

There is a array like that ---> [[text1, number1], [text2, number2]...]

I want to sort to this array(by first elements(texts)). This texts contains different characters such as ı, ç, ö... I found to location method but i couldn't use it. Also I want to describe own function.

Comment: How exactly do you define "alphabetically"? If you're given `ö ộ ȭ ò`, for example, what order are they supposed to come in?

Comment: Since the letters are not defined in your desired "alphabetical" order, you need to define your own sort function, including the desired order.

Comment: A B C Ç D E F G Ğ H I İ J K L M N O Ö P R S Ş T U Ü V Y Z

Comment: Are there any sample code? I'm working on this for 2 days. I have a homework but I don't have time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the sort method and specify the key as the first entry of every element in the list

```
import unicodedata 
def strip_accents(text):
    print("HIIIIIIII: %s"%text)
    return ''.join(char for char in
                   unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', text)
                   if unicodedata.category(char) != 'Mn')

l=[['ç', 2], ['ç', 10], ['a', 3], ['b', 1], ['d', 7]]
print(sorted(l, key=lambda k: strip_accents(k[0])))
print(l)
# [['a', 3], ['b', 1], ['ç', 2], ['ç', 10], ['d', 7]]
```

Refrences:

[Syntax behind sorted(key=lambda: ...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966538/syntax-behind-sortedkey-lambda)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4512721/8692977

Comment: Problem is that "my alphabet is a, b, c, ç, d... but if I use sort method, ç will be last character(ascii)"

Comment: Just made some modifications to the code to account for that @cedricdef

Answer (score 0):

Usually characters such as `ç` are alphabetically sorted after their non accentuated counterparts (`c`). In that sense, the encoding you are using may or may not help regarding sorting alphabetically.

I would suggest first defining your order relation:

[`a`, `á`, `à`, `b`, `c`, `ç`, ...]

Implementing a `<` compare function based on that relation, and using one of the many available sorting methods to sort your list.